# Command Prompt Multiple Commands on Startup

Tags: command-line

I have a command prompt shortcut in my start menu. What I have done is add /k prompt Commands$g.
I want a way to make it so I can do multiple commands after the /K. When I try, it just adds it to the end of the previous command.

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on windows PC (because I have not faced the same problem from linux pc), one thing you can do is that press "Windows Key" of your keyboard and type cmd and then repeat.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I want a command prompt command to run on command prompt startup. The command I want to run is /K prompt Commands$g